# xPath doesn't work Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

new to selenium here.

I tried finding an element wrapped in anchor tag through xPath with the following code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[.='Admin Login']")).Click();
```

But it doesn't work, it gives an error "method doesn't exist". While the following code does work:

```
 IWebElement element= driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Admin Login"));
 element.Click();
```

Why doesn't xPath work?

HTML (<> are removed for obvious reasons):
     a href="http://sample.com/admin" class="btn btn-block btn-style">  Admin Login /a

Comment: Try this `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()='Admin Login']")).Click();` or this: `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@name='Admin Login']")).Click();`

Comment: Tried both. It still gives the same error.

Comment: Are you not getting the WebElement object?

Comment: VS can't find the WebElement, it throws an exception when I run the xPath code

Comment: Can you find this element by ID? If so, that means selenium is not supporting searching anchors by attributes, which is pretty weird, knowing that Selenium's documentation never mention this. Can you add the html element in the question?

Comment: Is your anchor element inside a separate iFrame?

Comment: <a href="sample.com/sam" class="btn btn-block btn-style">  Admin Login</a>

Comment: Seems like there is a white space in the beginning of your Title. I would suggest this:

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()=' Admin Login']")).Click();`

Comment: Tried that, still throws an excpetion.
I copied xPath of from inspect panel and ran my code on it. It worked fine then.
" /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a[1] "

Comment: @ZairaZafar could you share exact error stack trace???

Comment: Any reason to NOT use xpath is a *great* reason. You found a by-locator that works, so use it instead of xpath.

Comment: Post the actual, full exception/error message. Also post the relevant HTML or preferably a link to the page.

Comment: Why -1 for my question? What is irrelevant?

Comment: @ZairaZafar Please post your HTML file with the question

Comment: It's a stage website of my company for testing, I can't provide you that due to employee contract and policy. I have added the html code though

Answer (score -1):

try

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'Admin Login')]")).Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(.,'Admin Login')]")).Click();
```